# pg_restore: Its not restoring my db

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

What does it mean I'm trying to restore my postgresql db and here is what I'm getting but I do not see it restore tables/data/

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pg_restore.exe --host
>   123-97.compute-1.amazonaws.com --port 5432 --username "username"
>   --dbname "mydb" --no-password  --section pre-data --section data --section post-data --schema public --verbose "C:\db\employee.backup"
>
> pg_restore: connecting to database for restore pg_restore: implied
>   data-only restore
>
> Process returned exit code 0.

I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: What's in your backup file? Are you sure it has useful content?

Comment: i have backup on my local machine and the size of that is 100 mb yes its my database that i used for the application... i do not know much about postgresql db or pgadmin just stuck in pg_restore

Comment: You're using all the `--section` options, which is the same as not specifying any at all, however, the warning you're getting (`implied data-only restore`) points to some kind of problem there, so you'll be better off with removing all `--section <type>` options from your command. Also, you're requesting restoring only the public schema, is this what you actually want to do?. Note that if the public schema is empty in your database, then the restore will do nothing.

Comment: Here's how data-only behavior is determined: (1) if you specify `--data-only` or (2) your dump is missing a schema or (3) you requested that no schema be restored.  https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/bin/pg_dump/pg_backup_archiver.c;h=87113cfd4421215c8ecf3b49220a2aa826513c0c;hb=e4c4e6258c747d440e161f387d2eff84a835ca08#l429

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this error while restoring schema backup with different name. When i restored the schema with same name it worked like a charm and then later I renamed it.

Alternative: do `pg_restore` from a carefully-restricted `pg_dump` dump and avoid `--schema` (and possibly even `--table`) options when using `pg_restore`.

Answer (score 0):

i faced same issue when tried to restore psql 12 backup into psql 12 database but with newer ubuntu version (backup was on ubuntu 18 and restore on ubuntu 20 ,both are psql 12).
when i downgraded ubuntu from 20 to 18 it restored just normally, not sure why ubuntu version should make problem. my advice just make sure environment of backup and restore are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

For backup purposes, rename your old schema eg. schema_old and create a new schema with the same name, and try to restore it again.